# Where is "imageUri" declared in this PhoneGap camera plug-in, Javascript example?

Tags: javascript, jquery, cordova, phonegap-plugins, phonegap

This must be a really newbie question that maybe has a lot more to do about how Javascript works than PhoneGap. I am following [this video](https://www.youpak.com/watch?v=RSWEgorgm6g) that simply takes a picture using the PhoneGap's camera plugin. [Here is](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-camera#module_camera.onSuccess) the camera plugin documentation. The code that does the work looks like this:

```html
navigator.camera.getPicture(function (imageUri) {
 
 var lastPhotoContainer = document.getElementById("lastPhoto");
 
 lastPhotoContainer.innerHTML = "<img src= '" + imageUri + "'style='width: 75%;' /> ";
 
}, null, null);
```

The plugin-in documentation at Cordova's site shows that the function definition looks like this:

```html
navigator.camera.getPicture(cameraSuccess, cameraError, cameraOptions);
```

So that anonymous function called in that first code snippet is the "cameraSuccess" callback. I get that. What I don't get is where is "imageUri" defined, because it perfectly shows the picture in the code part:

```html
lastPhotoContainer.innerHTML = "<img src= '" + imageUri + "'style='width: 75%;' /> ";
```

"imageUri" is a parameter passed to an anonymous function. My questions are: How these parameters works? Where is "imageUri" declared and how it contains the data???

Thank you!!

Answer (score 1):

The answer to this question was actually detailed in the documentation for the plugin which you linked! The web page states:

"Takes a photo using the camera, or retrieves a photo from the device's image gallery. ***The image is passed to the success callback as a Base64-encoded String***, or as the URI for the image file."

"imageUri" does not need to be instantiated within your code because it is being passed in to your function from code within the plugin.